# Python-OpenCV floodfill function; strange type errors

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, opencv

I am trying to implement my own version of the MatLab function imhmin() in Python using OpenCV and (naturally) NumPy. If you are not familiar with this MatLab function, it's extremely useful for segmentation. MatLab's documentation can explain it much better than I can:

https://it.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhmin.html

Here is what I have so far:

(For the sake of keeping this short, I did not include the local_min function. It takes one image parameter and returns an image of the same size where local minima are 1s and everything else is 0.)

```
from volume import show
import cv2
import numpy

def main():
    arr = numpy.array( [[5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
                        [5,0,3,1,4,2,5],
                        [5,5,5,5,5,5,5]] ) + 1

    res = imhmin(arr, 3)

    print(res)


def imhmin(src, h):
    # TODO: speed up function by cropping image

    edm = src.copy()

    # d is the domain / all values contained in the array
    d = numpy.unique(edm)

    # for the index of each local minima (sorted gtl)
    indices = numpy.nonzero(local_min(edm)) # get indices
    indices = numpy.dstack((indices[0], indices[1]))[0].tolist() # zip
    # sort based on the value of edm[] at that index
    indices.sort(key = lambda _: edm[_[0],_[1]], reverse = True)

    for (x,y) in indices:
        start = edm[x,y] # remember original value of minima

        # for each in a list of heights greater than the starting height
        for i in range(*numpy.where(d==edm[x,y])[0], d.shape[0]-1):
            # prevent exceeding target height
            step = start + h if (d[i+1] - start > h) else d[i+1]

            #-------------- WORKS UNTIL HERE --------------#

            # complete floodFill syntax:
            # cv2.floodFill(image, mask, seed, newVal[, loDiff[, upDiff[, flags]]]) → retval, rect

            # fill UPWARD onto image (and onto mask?)
            cv2.floodFill(edm, None, (y,x), step, 0, step-d[i], 4)

            # fill DOWNWARD NOT onto image
            # have you overflowed?


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which works fine until it gets to the floodfill line. It barks this error back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "edm.py", line 94, in <module>
    main()
  File "edm.py", line 14, in main
    res = imhmin(arr, 3)
  File "edm.py", line 66, in imhmin
    cv2.floodFill(edm, None, (y,x), step, 0, step-d[i], 4)
TypeError: Layout of the output array image is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)
```

At first I thought maybe the way I laid out the parameters was wrong because of the stuff about `step` in the traceback, but I tried changing that variable's name and have come to the conclusion that `step` is some variable name in OpenCV's code. It's talking about the output array, and I'm not using a mask, so something must be wrong with the array `edm`.

I can suppress this error by replacing the floodfill line with this one:

`cv2.floodFill(edm.astype(numpy.double), None, (y,x), step, 0, step-d[i], 4)`

The difference being that I am typecasting the numpy array to a float array. Then I am left with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "edm.py", line 92, in <module>
    main()
  File "edm.py", line 14, in main
    res = imhmin(arr, 3)
  File "edm.py", line 64, in imhmin
    cv2.floodFill(edm.astype(numpy.double), None, (y,x), step, 0, step-d[i], 4)
TypeError: Scalar value for argument 'newVal' is not numeric
```

This is where I started suspecting something was seriously wrong, because `step` is "obviously" going to be an integer here (maybe it isn't obvious, but I did try printing it and it looks like it's just an integer, not an array of one integer or anything weird like that).

To entertain the error message, I typecast the `newVal` parameter to a float. I got pretty much the exact same error message about the `upDiff` parameter, so I just typecast that too, resulting in this line of code:

`cv2.floodFill(edm.astype(numpy.double), None, (y,x), float(step), 0, float(step-d[i]), 4)`

I know this isn't how I want to be doing things, but I just wanted to see what would happen. What happened was I got this scary looking error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "edm.py", line 92, in <module>
    main()
  File "edm.py", line 14, in main
    res = imhmin(arr, 3)
  File "edm.py", line 64, in imhmin
    cv2.floodFill(edm.astype(numpy.double), None, (y,x), float(step), 0, float(step-d[i]), 4)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/9523d527-1b9e-48e0-7ed0-a36adde286f0/volume/opencv-suite_1535558719691/work/modules/imgproc/src/floodfill.cpp:587: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)  in function 'floodFill'
```

I don't even know where to start with this. I've used OpenCV's floodfill function many times before and have never run into problems like this. Can anyone provide any insight?

Thanks in advance

Antonio

Comment: The H-minima filter is typically implemented using an erosion by reconstruction (sup-reconstruction, see [here](http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/~lotufo/cursos/ia-870-2002/html/morph/mmsuprec.html)), applied to `image + h` and using the original `image` as conditioning image. There's [an implementation of morphological reconstruction in skimage](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.reconstruction).

Comment: Note that skimage also has [an h-minima filter](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.h_minima), though it does something different, it returns a binary image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the info Cris, I am trying to translate a larger project from MatLab to Python to be used in an even larger project. My forefront interest was not this function, so while I did look at the MatLab docs and glanced through MatLab's implementation, I kind of just came up with an approach that I thought would produce the same **result** instead of trying to copy their implementation. I'm still extremely new to image processing (and programming in general) and appreciate this information; I hope I can use it to improve my approach!

Comment: I’m suggesting this because it will be much, much faster than the approach you are attempting.